# How to use boost::bind to create a function wrapper

Tags: c++, boost, bind

I want to use boost::bind (I'm not sure if it is really the right solution to my problem) to create a wrapper to a function that takes one or two arguments, while the wrapper takes only one argument and fixes the other to some constant value. My functions look like

```
double f(double a, double b)
{
  return a/b;
}
```

or

```
double g(double b)
{
  return 2*b; // b+b?
}
```

In my code I have a typedef for a function with one argument:

```
typedef boost::function<double (double)> callback;
```

and my idea was to create the function wrapper with this:

```
callback cb;
cb = boost::bind(f, _1, 2)(x);
```

so that I could call a third function that *uses* a wrapped function passed in the arguments:

```
double use(callback cb, double x, double y)
{
  return cb(x0) - y0;
}
```

I have about 30 functions with one or two arguments, and the first or the second must be a constant. This constant is not known to `use()`, but the algorithm implemented in `use` works with every function.

When I try to compile my code, I get an error for the line `cb = boost::bind(f, _1, 2)(x);`:

```
'* f' cannot be used as a function
```

When I try to use the bind directly, as in `cout << boost::bind(f, _1, 2)(x);`, I don't get an error.

What have I done wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why add the `(x)`?

```
cb = boost::bind(f, _1, 2);
```

This already defines a wrapper of `f` which the second argument is 2, and you can call

```
cb(x0)
```

to get `f(x0, 2)`.

Comment: I added the `(x)` because all the examples in the `boost::bind` documentation do it. Now as you are pointing this out it seems clear, because the missing argument is filled in by `use()` and not known when the bind is done. It works now, thank you!